# What is the justification for translating se'eth as "accepted" in regards to Cain?

Tags: translation-philosophy, hebrew-bible

If thou doest well, shalt thou not be accepted? (Gen. 4:7 KJV). This is the only time this Hebrew word is translated as "accepted" and I'm looking for some justification for doing so.

Answer (score 2):

It is related to the verb נָשָׂא and used in antithesis to נָפְלוּ פָנֶיךָ in v. 6. It basically means “lifting up” or “rising.” That is, “If you do well, won’t there be a lifting up [of your face]?”—as opposed to a falling (cf. v. 5). The phrase “of your face” (פָנֶיךָ) is supplied by ellipsis from v. 5.

Keil wrote,<sup>1</sup>

> “Why art thou wroth, and why is thy countenance fallen?” The answer to this is given in the further question, “Is there not, if thou art good, a lifting up” (sc., of the countenance)? It is evident from the context, and the antithesis of falling and lifting up (נפל and נשׂא), that פּנים must be supplied after שׂאת.

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> p. [111–112](https://archive.org/details/biblicalcommenta00keil01/page/n113)

#### References

Keil, Carl Friedrich. [*Commentary on the Old Testament.*](https://archive.org/details/biblicalcommenta00keil01) 1900. Reprint. Trans. Martin, James. Vol. 1. Grand Rapids: Eerdmans, 1986.

Comment: Thank you for that, but then why isn't it translated as "happy" or the opposite of a "falling face." The word "accepted" is passive and seems to shift the meaning to being accepted by someone. In otherwords I can't square the Hebrew with the English, in spite of your helpful insight.

Comment: @JosephO.—You're right. I was being a bit too kind in my critique of the translation.

Comment: Here' a Jewish translation:       "Surely, if you do right, 
      There is uplift. 
      But if you do not do right 
      Sin couches at the door; 
      Its urge is toward you, 
      Yet you can be its master.” 


Jewish Publication Society. (1985). Tanakh: The Holy Scriptures (Ge 4:7). Philadelphia: Jewish Publication Society.

Comment: @PerryWebb ”There is uplift” - is that proper English?